# Dropdown controls in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-2.0

I am using a codebehind page in ASP.NET to perform a SQL query.  The query is loaded into a string, the connection is established (To Oracle), and we get it started by having the connection perform .ExecuteReader into a OleDBDataReader (We'll call it DataRead).  I'll try to hammer out an example below.  (Consider Drop as an ASP DropDownList control)

```
Dim LookFor as String = "Fuzzy Bunnies"

While DataRead.Read
    If LookFor = DataRead.Item("Kinds of Bunnies") Then
        'Meets special critera, do secondary function'

         Drop.Items.Add(DataRead.Item("Subgroup of Bunnies"))
         ...
    End if
    ...
End While
```

This is the only way I know of doing a dynamic add to a DropDownList.  However, each item in a DropDownList has a .text property and a .value property.  How can we define the .value as being different from the .text in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.add.aspx) function can take a [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx), so you can do

```
Dim li as new ListItem(DataRead.Item("Subgroup of Bunnies"), "myValue")
Drop.Items.Add(li)
```

Comment: Years later, I found this helpful again.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add should have an overload that accepts a ListItem object.  Using that, you can usually do something like this:

```
Drop.Items.Add(New ListItem("Text", "Value"))
```

Comment: You said pretty much exactly the same thing as me except about 30 seconds earlier.  Upvoted :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question, Items.Add has an overload that takes a ListItem, so you could create a new ListItem object in that line:

```
Drop.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value"))
```

Comment: Several people beat me to this answer

Comment: AaronSieb said the exact same thing while I was typing mine, so he really should get the upvote... I'll upvote him myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Pardon my possibly faulty VB

```
Dim item as New ListItem()
item.Value = "foo"
item.Text = "bar"

Drop.Items.Add(item)
```

You can also use the ListItem constructor (e.g. new ListItem("text", "value"))

Answer (score 0):

you'd select a second column into your datareader (such as an IDENTITY field) and then assign do your Item generation like this:

```
Dim item as new listitem
item.text = DataRead.Item("SubGroup Of Bunnies")
item.value = DataRead.Item("ID")
Drop.Items.Add(item)
```

You may also want to look into the DATABIND functionality, and filtering out "FUZZY BUNNIES" in the SQL statement itself.